# SequelizeDatabaseError: the operator does not exist : integer = boolean when using special methods on model instance

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I have two models in Many-to-Many association : Agency and Customer.

UPDATE : (here are the models and association definition)

Agency :

```js
const agency = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Agency = sequelize.define('agency', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true,
      }
    },
  });

  Agency.associate = models => {
    Agency.hasMany(models.User, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' });
    Agency.belongsToMany(models.Customer, { onDelete: 'SET NULL', through: 'CustomerAgencies'});
  };

  return Agency;
};

export default agency;
```

Customer :

```js
const customer = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Customer = sequelize.define('customer', {
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true,
        isEmail: true,
      },
    },
    firstname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true,
      }
    },
    lastname: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true,
      validate: {
        notEmpty: true,
      }
    },
    phone: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    language: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  });

  Customer.associate = models => {
    Customer.belongsToMany(models.Agency, { onDelete: 'SET NULL', through: 'CustomerAgencies'});
  };

  return Customer;
};

export default customer;
```

When i create some entries, there is no problem :

```js
  const agency = await models.Agency.findOrCreate({
    where: { name: 'SunTour'},
    defaults: {
      name: 'SunTour'
    }
  });

  const customer = await models.Customer.findOrCreate({
    where: { email: 'paulo@example.com' },
    defaults: {
      email: 'paulo@example.com',
      firstname: 'Paulo',
      lastname: 'Dena',
      phone: '0202020202',
    },
  });
```

But i'm trying to use the [special methods](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#special-methods-mixins-added-to-instances) of Sequelize that are available when two models are in relation.

Juste under the previous code example i wrote this to check is there is already an assocation between the two instances :

```js
debug(await customer[0].hasAgency(agency));
```

The node server return me the error below for this line :

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: the operator does not exist : integer = boolean

In the console the query executed is this one :

```sql
 SELECT "agency"."id" FROM "agencies" AS "agency" INNER JOIN "CustomerAgencies" AS "CustomerAgencies" ON "agency"."id" = "CustomerAgencies"."agencyId" AND "CustomerAgencies"."customerId" = 1 WHERE ((("agency"."id" = 1 OR "agency"."id" = false)));
```

You can see that Sequelize query is using "agency.id = false" in his condition, i guess that's the problem.

Note : i'm using a PostGreSQL Database.

I guess the problem come from the PostGreSQL Database, but what can i do ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add model definitions and association definitions to your post

Comment: I just updated my post with the models definition including the associations